# SQL to not display result if any condition fails

Tags: oracle, jpql

Here is my SQL query

```
Select prtyrel.prty_id, prtyrel.rel_id, ivprty.prty_type_cd 
from IVPTY ivprty 
join PRTY_REL prtyrel on ivprty.prty_id = prtyrel.prty_id 
where prtyrel.rel_id = 'ABC0123'
```

Above query returns below result

```
prty_id     |   rel_id      | prty_type_cd
PR1         |   ABC0123     | ORG
PR2         |   ABC0123     | ORG
PR3         |   ABC0123     | PER
```

My requirement is, if the **rel_id** associated to any **prty_id** has **prty_type_cd** *PER* then the query should not return any return. For above given data, query should not return any record.
Query should return result only when **prty_type_cd** is *ORG* for all the **prty_id** and associated **rel_id**

how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a normal SQL question (what is your RDMBS?) or is jpql an sql like language?

Comment: Wr are using Oracle DB. In application we are using JPQL which translates to above sql query.